# Where is the threshing floor of Atad?

Tags: genesis, geography

In Genesis 50:10 (NASB)

> When they came to **the threshing floor of Atad**, which is beyond the Jordan, they mourned there with a very great and sorrowful lamentation; and he observed seven days of mourning for his father.

Where is the threshing floor of Atad?

Comment: It would be helpful to this site if you would wait till other people answered your questions instead of accepting answers from @ Dottard all the time.

Comment: @Bagpipes if his answers were good and fast I simply accepted them. It's the first time someone brings up that up to me though but will have that in mind yes, thank you for being open about it.

Comment: You are very welcome my good man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are, again, two matters here:

**"Beyond the Jordan"**

Note the succinct statement of Ellicott -

> Beyond Jordan.—It is disputed whether this means on the east or on the
> west of the Jordan. It is certain that the route taken by Joseph lay
> to the east of the Dead Sea; for Goren-Atad is placed by Jerome at
> Beth-Hoglah, which lay between the Jordan and Jericho, and Joseph
> could have gone thither only by travelling through the territories of
> Moab and Amnion.  [He says much more about this but is inconclusive.]

**The Location**

Cambridge Bible for Schools and Colleges offers this -

> 10. the threshing-floor of Atad] Goren-ha-Atad, a threshing-floor of “the thornbush,” or “bramble” (Jdg 9:14-15). The place is nowhere else
>     referred to.

Ellicott makes this helpful remark -

> (10) Threshingfloor of Atad.—Atad means “a thorn-bush,” the rhamnus
> paliurus of Linnaeus, translated “bramble” in Judges 9:14. As
> agriculture was only beginning to be practised in Canaan, this
> threshing. floor would be common property, situated in some place easy
> of access, and probably a village would grow up near it.

**CONCLUSION**

Therefore, the short answer to the question - we do not know.